# Modify table in gsp from controller

Tags: jquery, html, grails, gsp

In my Grails project I have a GSP page with a JQuery table, with buttons that allows me to add / remove rows. I've created it following the tutorial [here](http://www.smarttutorials.net/invoice-system-using-jquery-autocomplete/)

I have implemented the save of table values inside DB (they refers to a domain class fields and objects, so I use the `save()` method of related controller), but I don't know how to fill the table with correct data in instance `edit()` method of controller.

Is there a way to add rows into a table in a gsp page from the controller, when user edits the instance?

Answer (score 3):

First and dirty way to do above task is to put your table code into a gsp template and update it by the response from Ajax request. But it's not optimize as in this way you have to request whole data again and again.

Second and more optimize way is to use javascript templating like [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) or [Hogan.JS](http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/). In this case you just need to request data in json format and then template will do all the work for you.

Third way is that you can use third part jquery based table to do all the work like display table, add, delete and edit any row data in it. Two of the most popular are Data Table and JqGrid.

Fourth and most optimize way of all is to leave Ajax and adopt AngularJS to do al the work like loading data, modifying data etc

Comment: can you provide some quick example of the ways you described above? first and second will be ok...

Answer (score 0):

From your GSP use ajax call to update table and refresh the table. The other option is that when you call update then use `redirect` to the controller action where where you list your table.

Comment: can you give me a quick example of how to do it?